# An für sich - richtig?

Tags: phrase

In einem Kommentar hier habe ich gelesen

> An für sich sollte....

Für mich klingt das falsch/extrem genuschelt. Ich kenne es nur so:

> An und für sich...

- Ist es ohne "und" gängig?
- Ist es regional unterschiedlich? (Ich bin Berliner)

Comment: Ich (Raum Frankfurt/Main) habe "an für sich" schon gehört und auch selbst benutzt, aber noch nie geschrieben gesehen. Spontan würde ich auch fast eher "anfürsich" schreiben wollen, während "an und für sich" ganz klar getrennt und ein anderer Ausdruck ist. Im Duden gibt es erstaunlicherweise nur "an und für sich", was mich jetzt doch überrascht hat.

Comment: Nebenbei: "[an sich](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/An_sich)" geht mindestens zurück auf Latein *per se* und antikes Griechisch bei Demokles und Sokrates als *kath-auto*, wobei *kata* (bzw. *kath*) verschiedene Bedeutungen annehmen kann, bekannt aus Worten wie *Ankathete, Kathode, Kathechismus, Katastrophe*. Da der geläufige Gegensatz zu *an* meist *ab* lautet, das aber oft eine treffende Bedeutung für *kata* ist, sowie *per* verwandt mit *für* ist ... ich frage mich, ob *Absicht* hierher gehört. Jedenfalls ist die *an und ein und ander gereihte* Aufzählung von Präpositionen äußerst üblich.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Laut Duden und Wiktionary sind "an und für sich" und "an sich" standardsprachlich korrekt.

Was die Umgangssprache angeht, scheint dieses Thema äußerst umstritten zu sein. Während viele "an für sich" ausdrücklich als falsch empfinden, sehen ebenso viele die Form als gängig oder zumindest nicht untypisch an.

Den Kommentaren zufolge bin ich also nicht der Einzige, dem ein Hinweis auf die in weiten Teilen Deutschlands durchaus nicht unübliche Variante "an für sich" fehlt.

Welche Regionen das exakt betrifft, kann ich nicht sagen, aber zumindest scheint es hauptsächlich in vielen Regionen im Süden und Westen verwendet zu werden. Das heißt nicht, dass es überall im Süden und Westen so sein muss.

Es finden sich sogar viele Verwendungen von "an für sich" im Internet.

Google Suche für [zeit.de](https://www.google.de/search?q=%22an%20f%C3%BCr%20sich%22%20site%3Azeit.de&client=opera&oe=utf-8&channel=suggest&gws_rd=ssl&oq=%22an%20f%C3%BCr%20sich%22%20site%3Azeit.de&gs_l=heirloom-serp.3...4478.4753.0.4866.4.4.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0.msedr...0...1ac.1.34.heirloom-serp..4.0.0.pS_-NL0i5iU), [spiegel.de](https://www.google.de/search?q=%22an%20f%C3%BCr%20sich%22%20site%3Aspiegel.de&client=opera&oe=utf-8&channel=suggest&gws_rd=ssl&oq=%22an%20f%C3%BCr%20sich%22%20site%3Aspiegel.de&gs_l=heirloom-serp.3...67423.68134.0.68341.7.6.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0.msedr...0...1ac.1.34.heirloom-serp..7.0.0.Np5gAfBcreA), [sueddeutsche.de](https://www.google.de/search?q=%22an%20f%C3%BCr%20sich%22%20site%3Asueddeutsche.de&client=opera&oe=utf-8&channel=suggest&gws_rd=ssl&oq=%22an%20f%C3%BCr%20sich%22%20site%3Asueddeutsche.de&gs_l=heirloom-serp.3...50929.50929.0.51054.1.1.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0.msedr...0...1ac.1.34.heirloom-serp..1.0.0.EDK4vza-rJo)

Comment: Ich halte das (Ostösterreicher) nicht für korrekt. Kann schon sein, dass das "und" genuschelt oder mal beinahe verschluckt wird, aber (zumal schriftlich) weglassen kann man es mE nicht.

Comment: @Ingmar: Natürlich ist es noch nicht korrekt. Aber der Sprachwandel läuft eben oft so, dass ein unbetontes Wort immer häufiger genuschelt oder verschluckt wird. In einer Übergangszeit glauben die Älteren es ansatzweise zu hören, auch wenn es ganz verschwunden ist, während die Jüngeren schon damit aufgewachsen sind, dass es manchmal ganz fehlt, und das für eine (korrekte oder falsche) Variante halten. Diese Variante wird dann immer häufiger auch aufgeschrieben, zunächst in der direkten Rede, später auch außerhalb - bis sie vielleicht irgendwann als korrekt gilt.

Comment: Vielleicht, irgendwann. Wobei gerade der Duden ja sowieso keinerlei Anspruch mehr erhebt normativ zu sein, sondern einen vollständig beschreibenden Standpunkt eingenommen hat. Wenn es aber nicht einmal dort zu finden ist darf man getrost davon ausgehen dass es zum gegenwärtigen Zeitpunkt schlicht & ergreifend falsch ist.

Comment: Ich bevorzuge "An Pfirsich", vong 1 Sprache her.

Answer (score 8):

Korrekt heißt es *an und für sich*. *An für sich* gibt es als Ausdruck nicht.

Comment: Das ist korrekt. Im Sprachgebrauch kenne ich (und einige meiner Bekannten) allerdings nur *An für sich*. Obwohl *An und für sich* richtig ist, habe ich das noch nie gehört. Viele Grüße aus dem Süden von Deutschland.

Comment: Schließe mich @Kai an, hier im Süden wird das _und_ fast immer weggelassen.

Comment: Ich bin auch im Süden aufgewachsen und haben "an für sich" noch nie gehört, eher so etwas wie "an e fürsich" oder "an a fürsich" also eine knappe Kontrakur.

Comment: Also ich komme auch aus dem Süden - die Enklave, wo *an für sich* gesagt wird, habe ich jedoch noch nicht gefunden. Ehrlich gesagt habe ich *an für sich* heute zum ersten Mal überhaupt gelesen, vorher noch nie gehört oder gelesen...

Answer (score 2):

"An für sich" ist grammatikalisch falsch. Man benutzt aber in der gesprochenen Sprache, besonders in Westfalen, gerne "anufürsich", also eine gequetschte Version des Ausdrucks.
Dementsprechend lässt sich streiten, ob "an für sich" so sinnvoll ist oder eben nicht.

Comment: Die Kontraktion--den anderen Kommentaren anschließend--wäre schon sinnvoll, nach dem Schema "schwarz-weiß meliert". Die Schreibung des Idioms wäre demnach zweitrangig. Ein anderes Beispiel wäre sicher besser, Insofern es sich um die Betonung einer Vereinigung, nicht der Gegenüberstellung zweier Konzepte handelt. Ich frage mich nach allen Antworten immer noch, wie die Redner "an Pfirsich" für sich verstehen, hat immerhin Philosophische Tradition. Ich kannte und mag daher den Ausdruck nicht, es als *falsch* zu bezeichnen geht aber zu weit. Mich nervt nur das ganze *Hin-Her*.

Answer (score 0):

Die Form ohne *und* ist jedenfalls schon seit langem auch im schriftsprachlichen Gebrauch. Vier Belege von [archive.org](https://archive.org/) habe ich beigefügt, es ließen sich leicht mehr nennen. Man muß allerdings sagen, daß die Form ohne *und* sehr viel seltener auftritt als die mit.

> Zweitens, dass der Verf. in Vertheidigung der, **an für sich** schon widersinnigen, Behauptung, jede Arbeit sei productiv, ausdrücklich erörtert, wie selbst der Mordbrenner etwas erzeuge. (R. Mohl, "Uebersicht über die neueren Leistungen der Neapolitaner und Sicilianer im Gebiete der politischen Oekonomie", 1844, [S. 229](https://archive.org/details/jstor-40734542/page/n7))
>
> Ein Krankheitsvorgang, welcher in seiner Wesenheit mit Eiterbildung verbunden ist und der in nicht direct zugänglichen [...] Gewebsschichten verläuft, ist schon **an für sich** nach unsern heutigen Kenntnissen und möglichen Eingriffen für jene Vornahmen unzugänglich, welche die gestellte Aufgabe in vollem Maasse lösen könnten; [...] (Ernst Schwimmer, *Zur Therapie der Variola vom Standpunkte der Micrococcuslehre*, 1880, [S. 38](https://archive.org/details/39002086346864.med.yale.edu/page/38))
>
> Nun ist es aber leider **an für sich** und naturgemäsz der fall, dasz uns gerade die scharfe specialisierung der worte im Rgveda schwer wird; im umgekerten Verhältnis ihrer leichtigkeit ist sie aber bedürfnis. (Alfred Ludwig, *Ueber Methode bei Interpretation des Rgveda*, 1890, [S. 21](https://archive.org/details/uebermethodebei00ludwgoog/page/n24))
>
> Der Fund der Zisterne in der Kirche wäre **an für sich** nicht weiter auffallend gewesen. (Karl Maria Kaufmann, *Die Menasstadt und das Nationalheiligtum der altchristlichen Aegypter in der westalexandrinischen Wüste*, 1910, [S. 82](https://archive.org/details/ldpd_7138227_000/page/n91))